# Use ImageMagick to convert TIFF to PNGs, how to improve the speed?

Tags: conversion, compression, png, tiff

I am using "convert" from IM to get PNGs from multi-page TIFF files, everything is good except the speed. From "convert" documentation, I found:

> For the MNG and PNG image formats, the quality value sets the zlib compression level (quality / 10) and filter-type (quality % 10). For compression level 0, the Huffman-only strategy is used, which is fastest but not necessarily the worst compression. The default PNG compression is 75.**

I tried "-quality 0", but there were almost no changes to the speed.

Can anyone share their ideas on how to improve the spreed? Here is my command:

```
convert 100Pages.tif[0,1,2,3,4,5] -quality 0 100Pages.png
```

Comment: Your probably not going to gain much speed unless you work from a faster computer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) which is a derivative of ImageMagick and claims to have many improvements, including performance. I have not tried it myself.